# State-dependent aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I'm fairly new to MongoDB so forgive me if this question has a simple answer.

I'm trying to design a query that aggregates across event-generated documents' "states". In particular, I'm interested in the time "spent" in each state.

Let's say I have a MongoDB collection with the following schema:

```
{
 timestamp: {type: Number, required: true},
 state: {type: Number, required: true}
}
```

I want to generate a list of states and the amount of time spent in each state. For example, if I have the following documents (ordered by timestamp),

```
{timestamp: 100, state: 0},
{timestamp: 102, state: 1},
{timestamp: 110, state: 1},
{timestamp: 120, state: 0},
{timestamp: 123, state: 1}
```

then I would like to produce `[{state: 0, time: 5}, {state: 1, time: 18}]` where the first entry's time is due to (102-100)+(123-120) and the second entry's time is due to (120-102).

I'm aware that Mongo's aggregation framework uses streams, so it seems like this sort of state-dependent aggregation would be pretty straightforward. However, I haven't come across such a mechanism or a term for this kind of technique yet.

Any suggestions? Is there a built-in mechanism to do something like this?

Comment: In fact, this isn't straightforward using aggregation, as the pipeline processes one document at a time. There are a few math operators, but it's not clear how they'd be used in your scenario as it's more complex than a sum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question with the solution I ended implementing.

I realized that I was really interested in the *previous* state of each document. In my case documents are inserted in large batches in temporal order. So, I simply created a `state_prev` field and a `delta` field (the difference between sequential documents' `timestamp` values).

```
{
  timestamp: Number,
  state: Number,
  state_prev: Number,
  delta: Number
}
```

I'm now able to `$sum` the new `delta` field and `$group` by the `state_prev` field to achieve my desired aggregate computation.